# Facebook doesn't take from my app the auth for user_posts

Tags: facebook

I've made an application that use this scope (v. 2.4):

```
publish_actions,email,user_posts
```

when I try to autenticate my user (using the one that create the app) it shows me the three permissions to accept, correctly.

But when I use another user, it only asks to accept publish actions and email. `user_posts` is ignored. So I can't get the post of that user. This is the endpoint for autenticate users:

https://www.facebook.com/v2.4/dialog/oauth?response_type=token&client_id=MyID&redirect_uri=MyRedirectURL&scope=user_posts%2Cemail%2Cpublish_actions

What should I enable to make the application work (i.e. all auth) for all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to request permissions from all users instead of only the app's admins/developers/testers, your app has to pass Facebook Login Review.

It's all in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Comment: Oh my god! So for every app that doesn't use those 3 standard permission I need to made a Review with screenshoots/and so on. Very huge works...

Comment: Yes, since nearly 1,5 years this is the case.

Comment: How is that very huge works? You just need to explain how you use the permission and how the reviewer test it

Comment: It has been worked till now. Now can't works because its deprecated. Huge works because sometimes I can't expose link outside of my agency (private domain), I need to do screenshoot, waiting 5 days, and slow down the whole process for get some user informations.